# What does Allocation.generateMipmaps do?

Tags: renderscript

I'm trying to downsample an image using renderscript and it looks like `Allocation.generateMipmaps()` does something like that. I don't have a graphics background, but it seems like it does a series of downsamples.

Does it work and what do I have to do to set it up in such a way that I can retrieve 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 sized images?

Comment: void android::RSC::Allocation::generateMipmaps (  ) 
Generate a mipmap chain. This is only valid if the Type of the Allocation includes mipmaps. This function will generate a complete set of mipmaps from the top level LOD and place them into the script memory space. If the Allocation is also using other memory spaces, a call to syncAll(Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT) is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
void android::RSC::Allocation::generateMipmaps  ()
```

Generate a mipmap chain. This is only valid if the Type of the Allocation includes mipmaps. This function will generate a complete set of mipmaps from the top level LOD and place them into the script memory space. If the Allocation is also using other memory spaces, a call to `syncAll(Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)` is required.

Alternatively you can get all the methods for work here:
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/renderscript/classandroid_1_1RSC_1_1Allocation.html#a3c9f32ff3070f8a38e3a8c6e58ed7a82

Comment: Yes, I saw this. But I'm not able to understand how do I retrieve the mipmaps from the script memory. I can have an allocation that is WxH size with the MIPMAPS_FULL flag and then run generateMipmaps(). But how do I, for example, pull out the 1/2 size data and put it into a bitmap object?